# How to display custom taxonomy and terms using/creating plugin template

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, templates, taxonomy, terms

I am working on a plugin which requires a custom taxonomy and 3 terms (Personal, Group & Pets). I already have the taxonomy set up with terms and some sample posts. I've created a template for my custom taxonomy which currently shows the same output for each category(term). I need the output to display only the posts within the current selected term. So if viewing from `example.com/user_image_category/group/` - it should display only the posts for "group".

**Please note** I'm trying to do this without touching the theme folder. And, I apologize if the code is a bit... gross, to say the least. I've pieced together a few things I've found but have fixed quite a bit - I usually deal with themes and SMALL plugins.

plugin function:

```
add_filter('template_include', 'sui_user_image_cat_template', 99);
             custom taxonomy / category
function sui_user_image_cat_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_tax('sui_image_category') ) {
        $new_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'templates/taxonomy-user_image_category.php';
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

`taxonomy-user_image_category.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * user_images_category taxonomy archive
 */

get_header(); 

?>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">

<h2>Contest Photos: </h2><br />


<div id="category-navigation">
  <?php
    // put these in UL LI format if time allows

    $terms = get_terms('sui_image_category');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $term_link = get_term_link($term, 'user_images');
      if( is_wp_error($term_link) )
        continue;
      echo '<span class="category-link"><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></span> ';
    }
  ?>
<br /><br />
</div>



<div id="gridContainer">
<?php
$c = 1; //init counter
$bpr = 3; //boxes per row


  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'user_images',
    'post_status' => 'publish'    
  );

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);  

  if($posts->post_count){

      foreach($posts->posts as $user_image){
        $user_info = get_userdata($user_image->post_author);    
        $user_image_cats = get_the_terms($user_image->ID, 'sui_image_category');

        foreach($user_image_cats as $cat){
          $user_image_cat = $cat->name;
        }

        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($user_image->ID);

  ?>
      <div class="contest-entry" id="post-<?php echo $post_thumbnail_id ?>">
        <div class="contest-image">
          <?php echo wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id, 'medium'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="votes half left-align">&hearts;</div>
          <div class="category half right-align">
            <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat) ?>">
              <?php echo $user_image_cat ?>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p class="image-caption"><?php echo $user_image->post_title ?></p>
        <a class="author" href="#"><?php echo $user_info->user_login ?></a>
      </div>

      <?php if($c == $bpr) : ?>

        <div class="clr"></div>

      <?php $c = 0;
        endif;
      ?>
    <?php
      $c++;
    }  
  };

?>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>

  </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `taxonomy-user_image_category.php` the [`get_queried_object`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) method will return the term object, which you can incorporate to your `WP_Query`. From top of my head, in your case it may look like this:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'user_images',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => array(
      array(
          'taxonomy' => 'sui_image_category',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $term_id
      )
   )
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I didn't even think it would be that easy.